# Creating a new polygon feature class with specific coordinates in PyScripter

Tags: geometry, coordinates, polygon

I am trying to create a new polygon feature class containing a single square polygon with the following coordinates: (0,0),(0,1000),(1000,0), AND (1000,1000), but my script keeps hitting a "VauleError: too many values to unpack" at the line "ID, X, Y = string.split(line, " ")"
Here is the rest of my script:

```
import arcpy
import fileinput
import string
import os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "E:/UNIVERSITY/Exercise08"
env.overwriteOutput = True
outpath ="E:/UNIVERSITY/Exercise08"
newfc = "Results/newpolygon.shp"

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newfc, "Polygon")
infile = "E:/UNIVERSITY/Exercise08/challengecoordinates.txt"
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc, ["SHAPE@"])
array = arcpy.Array()
for line in fileinput.input(infile):
    ID, X, Y = string.split(line, " ")
    array.add(arcpy.Point(X, Y))
cursor.insertRow([arcpy.Polygon(array)])
fileinput.close()
del cursor
```

Comment: What does a line of `challengecoordinates.txt` look like? It's probably a misformatted line in that file that doesn't have the necessary two spaces to unpack into three elements.

Comment: like so:
01 0 0 0 1000 1000 1000 1000 0

Answer (score 2):

The line `01 0 0 0 1000 1000 1000 1000 0` won't unpack correctly, splitting on space will make a list of 9 elements from that line, and you're only assigning 3: (id, x, y).

Instead, you should take the line, and break it up into the parts you need for each component:

```
 parts = line.split(" ")
 id = parts[0] # 01
 coord1 = "({},{})".format(parts[1], parts[2]) # 0 0 in input, output (0, 0)
 <...>
 coord4 = "({},{})".format(parts[7], parts[8]) # 1000 0 in input, output (1000, 0)
```

From there you should be able to join together your coordinates into the WKT that you described.